# How To Use .VBS to create WiFi HotSpot "General Spcific"

Tags: vbscript, cmd, wifi

I am fairly new at .VBS and I've hit a bump. I'm trying to create a script that will allow me to automatically create a hotspot from any laptop, that the program is opened on. The bump I hit is that I cant find a way to automatically obtain the username@domain from command prompt and turned into a variable to be later injected into the coding. This is what I have so far:

```
    msgbox("Close Me And Run As Administrator")

    name=inputbox("Set SSID (WiFi Name)")
    pass=inputbox("Password For WiFi")

    strCmd="net wlan set hostnetwork mode=allow ssid=name key=pass"
    set objShell=CrateObject("wscript.shell")
    objShell.Run runas /user: "strCmd" 'this is why I need to figure out how to store and inject those variables
    strCMd="net wlan set hostnetwork mode=allow ssid=name key=pass"
    set objShell=CrateObject("wscript.shell")
    objShell.Run runas /user: "strCMd"
```

and then the rest is just msgbox telling them how to finish if they want to set up file sharing (i.e. xbox, ps3 or other computers on network)

Answer (score 0):

A little search on Google and I got this: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_network_names_domain.php

Comment: thank you this helped out. im currently deployed so I don't have much time to dedicate to searching my apologies